# Pass the names of the selected files from "Send To" menu to powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames

I have a script that I wrote that is added to the "Send To" menu already, and it asks for a search string and then searches every .log and .txt file in that directory for the string.

But what I need it to do is look at the file I am right clicking on and collect the name so I can use it as the only file to search in.

So if you can help me grab the name of the file I am right clicking on, and then "send to" my PowerShell script.
Thanks

Comment: Ditto to what' mklement0' says, but if you were using Out-Gridview for file selection, you can use -PassThru to get the name and then process other code off that name.  OGV details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.2 --- Example 7: Pass multiple items through `Out-GridView`

Answer (score 3):

Create a shortcut in your "SendTo" folder:

- Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, enter `shell:sendto`
- Create a shortcut with this target:

  - for Windows PowerShell:

    ```text
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File "FullPathToYourScript.ps1"
    ```
  - for PowerShell 7+:

    ```text
    "%ProgramFiles%\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -File "FullPathToYourScript.ps1"
    ```

When the "Send to" menu item is invoked, the system appends the full paths of the selected files to the commandline. In your PowerShell script, use the automatic `$args` array variable to get the file paths from the commandline arguments.

This demo shows how you can get the number of selected files and loop over the paths:

```sh
"Received $($args.Count) files:"

foreach( $path in $args ) {
    "Processing file: $path"    
}
```