# how can install apk files by double clicking on it using batch file

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, installation, apk

I want to write a batch file that help me to installing apk files when I double click on any apk file

for example when I click on apk file myBatchFile.bat execute

what should be in myBatchFile.bat

```
adb install what?
```

thanks

Comment: how about the path to your apk file?

Comment: yes
I dont know how can I receive clicked file's address in batch files

Comment: I think you want a droplet behaviour for your bat script.  this should help http://stackoverflow.com/q/8547676/794088

Answer (score 5):

First, backup the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes` registry hive. So you can restore settings if something goes wrong during testing of `.bat` files.

You need to install the shell handler of `.apk` files. The handler is a `.bat` file, say `MyApkInstaller.bat`. When you double click on a `.apk` file in Windows Explorer the handler `MyApkInstaller.bat` will be run and the `.apk` file name will be passed to the handler.

```
@echo off

echo Installing %1...
adb install %1 && echo Done || echo Failed
pause
```

The script that will install/uninstall the handler into Windows Registry

```
@echo off
setlocal

set _progId=MyApkInstaller
set _handler=MyApkInstaller.bat

if not "%1"=="" goto uninstall

:install
echo Installing...
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\.apk\OpenWithProgIds /v %_progId% /t REG_SZ /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\%_progId%\Shell\Open\Command /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0%_handler% ""%%1""" /f
goto finish

:uninstall
echo Uninstalling...
reg delete HKCU\Software\Classes\.apk
reg delete HKCU\Software\Classes\%_progId%

:finish
endlocal
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write these into your **xxx.bat**

```
@echo %1

adb install -r %1

pause
```

Setting the environment variables is necessary, open the **xxxx.apk** by choosing the way of **xxx.bat**

Answer (score 1):

The `adb` can install the `*.apk` on emulator as follows:

```
adb install PATH
```

so, you can simply create a batch file like this:

```
@echo off

echo installing your application...
adb install %1
```

and after save it, choose this batch file for default application of `*.apk` files. (***apk file in explorer > right click > properties > change > YOUR_BATCH_FILE***)